# Is it possible to temporarily replace one class with another?

Tags: groovy

I'm writing a unit test for a method which gets various information from an instance of a `Patient` class. The `Patient` class is a really complicated container around a bunch of other stuff which makes it possible to get information easily by doing things like `patient.demographics.firstName`. It's not possible to create a "real" Patient without turning my unit test into an integration test.

The obvious solution would be to replace `Patient` with `Map`. If this was Python I could just do `Patient = dict` and get on with my life, but I haven't been able to find any equivalent in Groovy==all I could find was replacing methods. From the somewhat minimal information on testing in Groovy it seems like I could maybe use map coercion as an overly complicated substitute, but I consider that a last resort.

The code in question is `Patient lpatient = app.createLegacyPatient(payload.patientId.toLong())`, and I'd already mocked the createLegacyPatient method to return a map. Problem is, a Map object is not a Patient object and trying to cast it to Patient doesn't work.

Is there any way in Groovy to say "this class is now this other class until I say different?" In other words, is it possible to do something so that `new Patient()` will actually return a `Map` object?

Comment: It really depends because Groovy can create a proxy, but proxies are not always accepted by the code being "tricked". Please post an example of code using a `Patient` for which a `Map` was not sufficient.

Comment: I can't really post more than I have (this is for work), but it seems the answer to the question is pretty clearly "no." For what it's worth, I ended up avoiding the problem by changing `Patient lpatient` to `def lpatient`. I'd been reluctant to do that originally, because that was code written by a full employee at the company I'm a contractor for, but, well... static typing sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy comes with an [Expando](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Expando.html) class, which I think will suit your needs. Here's an example:

```
def patient = new Expando()

patient.demographics = [ firstName : "John", lastName : "Galt" ]

assert patient.demographics.firstName == "John"
```

You can also initialize the `Expando` with a `Map`:

```
def map = [
    demographics : [
        firstName : "John", lastName : "Galt" 
    ]
]

def patient = new Expando(map)

assert patient.demographics.firstName == "John"
```

In many cases, just using a `Map` is sufficient:

```
def patient = [
    demographics : [
        firstName : "John", lastName : "Galt" 
    ]
]

assert patient.demographics.firstName == "John"
```

Comment: I guess my question was unclear. I've updated it. I tried passing an Expando, but ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, map coercion is the preferred way in Groovy to mock objects

```
def patient = [
   demographics : [
      firstName : "John", lastName : "lennon" 
   ]
] as Patient

assert patient.demographics.lastName == "lennon"
```

and that's all. You just created a Patient object using a Map like you used to in Python